# OneSignal Push Notification: How to set segment filter in code instead in the website

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to use One Signal Push Notification and it is a great app so far. I currently have a question regarding how to set segment filter in the code. So my user would be able to create an event and right after they create this event, all user within certain miles will be notified. One Signal has a cool thing, where it can help track the user's location and send notification base on where the user is. So I used the following code to get the user's location. I can put the user into segments and then filter by giving some inputs on the website. Like the screen shot, but I was wondering how would I achieve this in code? So I don't have to go to the website to write this. 
[The user interface on One Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8y6S.png)
window.plugins.OneSignal.promptLocation();

Comment: After searching online for a long time, it seems like OneSignal does not support client-side filter modification? OneSignal stuff, let me know if I am wrong. If that is the case, is it possible for me to get all user's current location some how even if the app is not running?

Comment: Or even set each user's tag base on their geolocation?

Answer (score 0):

According to OneSignal document:

Segments may only be created from the Dashboard, but segments may be referenced from the SDK and API.
There are no limits on the number of filters you may add to a segment or the number of segments you may create in OneSignal.

You can set filters in your code.
[Send to Users Based on Filters](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-to-users-based-on-filters)

> Filters are a powerful way to target users, allowing you to use both data that OneSignal has about a user and any Tags your app may send OneSignal.